# Trying to move octobercms to custom cms . Get hashed image path from octobercms

Tags: octobercms

I wanna to move website in octobercms to custom cms . But in october cms photos path is hashed in system_files table . How can I get its path ? Is it even possible

Comment: check this out to get the path of images https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699666/october-export-file-url-to-database, yes its possible to get path using `path`

Answer (score 0):

Like Hardik mentioned in his comment, yes it's possible.
You can use this [other post as a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58038452/list-files-from-the-media-in-the-frontend-octobercms/58039162#58039162)

The main idea is to use [MediaLibrary's Api](https://octobercms.com/docs/api/system/classes/medialibrary)

```
$folder = '/';
$mediaLib = \System\Classes\MediaLibrary::instance();     
$files = $mediaLib->listFolderContents($folder);
$this['mediaFiles'] = $files;
foreach ($files as $file) {
    // Do something with file path
    echo $file->path
}
```